# retrofit.RetrofitError: 404 Not Found

Tags: android, api, service, get, retrofit

I am working on an android application that utilizes Retrofit to make api calls. When I call the following code:

```java
String searchText = query;
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint("https://mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.mashape.com")
        .build();
WordsApiService wordsApi = restAdapter.create(WordsApiService.class);
wordsApi.getWordDefinition(query, new Callback<WordsResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void success(WordsResponse wordsResponse, Response response) {
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
        System.out.println(error.getResponse().getStatus());
    }
});
```

With the following service:

```java
public interface WordsApiService {

    @Headers({
            "X-Mashape-Key : *insert real api key*",
            "Accept: text/plain"
    })
    @GET("/define/")
    void getWordDefinition(@Query("word") String word, Callback<WordsResponse> callback);

}
```

I am getting a 404 error (retrofit.RetrofitError: 404 Not Found).
When I go into mashape, I see that the service call is going through and hitting the api.

Am I missing something obvious in terms of the configuration of the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the forward slash from the ["define" endpoint](https://www.mashape.com/community/urban-dictionary#define) path.
Also, the query param is "term" and not "word"

```java
public interface WordsApiService {
    @Headers({
        "X-Mashape-Key : *insert real api key*",
        "Accept: text/plain"
    })
    @GET("/define")
    void getWordDefinition(@Query("term") String term, Callback<WordsResponse> callback);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. I really wish there was more documentation for Retrofit. As a noobie when it comes to api consumption, feels like I'm stumbling around in the dark.