# Using Retrofit with Restfull Post WebServices

Tags: android, web-services, rest, retrofit, restful-url

I'm trying to use `Retrofit` with `Restful WebService`. Everything seems alright, but somehow when I run this code this will always returns this

`Method not found. Retrofit 404 Error`

Here is my WebServices Code

```
public function processApi() {

    $func = strtolower(trim(str_replace("/","",$_POST['request'])));

    if ((int)method_exists($this,$func) > 0) {
        $this->$func();
    } else {
        // If the method not exist with in this class, response would be "Page not found".
        $this->response('Method not found',404);
    } 
}

private function login() {

    // Cross validation if the request method is POST else it will return "Not Acceptable" status
    if ($this->get_request_method() != "POST") {
        // If invalid inputs "Bad Request" status message and reason
        $error = array('status' => "0", "msg" => "Bad Request");
        $this->response($this->json($error), 406);  
    }

    // Input validations
    if (empty($email) and empty($password)) {

        $error = array('status' => "0", "msg" => "Invalid Email address or Password");
        $this->response($this->json($error), 400);
    }   
}



public class ObjectPost {

    @SerializedName("request")
    String request;
    @SerializedName("email")
    String event_id;

    public void setRequest(String request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    public void setEvent_id(String event_id) {
        this.event_id = event_id;
    }
}
```

And here is my Android Request Code

```
public class RestClient {

    public interface ClientInterface {

        @POST(Config.LOGIN_URL)
        void login(@Body ObjectPost mObject,
            Callback<LoginBeans> callback);

    }

    public static ClientInterface initRestAdapter() {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        return (ClientInterface) new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .setClient(new OkClient(client))
                .setEndpoint(Config.SERVER_URL)
                .build()
                .create(ClientInterface.class);

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with your browser? You configured retrofit to have full log level. What does the log say?

Comment: Method not found. Retrofit 404 Error

Comment: have you try in browser? And please ask your back end developer is header pass in webservice or not.

Comment: This question is probably the repeat of This one(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29761257/retrofit-retrofiterror-404-not-found), check this out it might help you.

Comment: @SandeepSingh  how u resolved ? i m also facing same issue ?

Comment: @Erum if you found any solution. Please also tell me too.

Answer (score 0):

The value in the

> Config.LOGIN_URL

Is most likely incorrect. Please remember that

> Config.SERVER_URL

Must contain the **base** URL address. e.g. http://www.server.com/ (also please note the slashes are **important**)

Next, what is in your attribute must be only the remainder of the specific method that would be appended on that **base** url. e.g. if the method you want to call is *login*, it should be

> @POST("/login")

Once again, I am not kidding about the slashes. 

Also remember that if a query parameter is sent through as null, retrofit ignores it (you may face this problem later).

If you need any further help, you already have your loglevel set to full, please add the logcat to your question so we can see what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But here are my parameters details
public static final String LOGIN_URL="/login";
public static final String SERVER_URL="http://xxyxyx.com";

Comment: Could you post the logcat produced by retrofit? Just remove the sensitive data - but if we can see that we might be able to see why.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks alright.

Basically you need to make sure your backend. Ensure that the controller or whatever is actually right.

Maybe this will be quite applicable to you https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/789

So, instead of looking at your Android code, it's a good reason to look somewhere else I would say.